# Select Max Value from a set of values with the same id

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have these two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Category (

CategoryID int NOT NULL,
CategoryName varchar(255),

PRIMARY KEY (CategoryID)
);

CREATE TABLE Team (

CategoryID int NOT NULL,
TeamName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
Points int(255),

PRIMARY KEY (TeamName),
FOREIGN KEY (CategoryID) REFERENCES Category(CategoryID)
);
```

I want to find the team with the most points from every category.

So far i have tried these, i know they are wrong, but im on dead-end. Any advice will be helpful.

```
SELECT category.categoryid, team.teamname, MAX(team.points)
FROM category, team
GROUP BY team.teamname
HAVING MAX(team.points);


select category.categoryid, team.teamname
from category
right join team on team.categoryid = category.categoryid
group by team.teamname
having max(team.points);


select team.categoryid, team.teamname
from team, team a
having max(team.points);


select category.categoryid, team.teamname, max(team.points), team.points
from team
inner join category on category.categoryid = team.categoryid
group by teamname
having (select distinct max(team.points) from team);


select category.categoryid, team.teamname, team.points
from team
inner join category on category.categoryid = team.categoryid;
```

Comment: `RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY CategoryID ORDER BY Points DESC) rnk` in CTE and `WHERE rnk = 1` in outer query.

Comment: Well `int(50)` WOW

Comment: @Akina Can you take a moment to explain what this does? I'm new to SQL and I'd rather fully understand what I'm doing, than copy paste it

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes i know, sorry!

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_rank and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to find the team with the most points from every category.

```
WITH cte AS ( SELECT *, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY CategoryID ORDER BY Team.Points DESC) rnk
              FROM Category 
              NATURAL JOIN Team )
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rnk = 1
```

But if there is more then one team in a category with the same maximal points then all of them will be returned.

If you need only one of them in this case, then additional ordering needed (and it must provide rows uniqueness). For example, it can be

```sql
WITH cte AS ( SELECT *, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY CategoryID ORDER BY Team.Points DESC, Team.TeamName) rnk
              FROM Category 
              NATURAL JOIN Team )
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rnk = 1;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5c73ac6a99e270535c70b173a65c02ff

Of course you may select only needed columns< i.e. `SELECT CategoryName, TeamName`.

Answer (score 0):

Version 8.0 supports `dense_rank()`

```
SELECT teamname
FROM (
    SELECT categoryid, teamname,
       dense_rank() over(partition by categoryid order by points desc) rnk
    FROM team
)t
WHERE rnk = 1
GROUP BY teamname
HAVING count(*) = (SELECT count(*) FROM Category);
```

Comment: What is the need in final GROUP BY and HAVING? `dense_rank` did everything already..

Comment: @Akina - "most points from every category."

Comment: And what row per category is filterred by `WHERE rnk = 1`?

Comment: When a team has rank=1 from one category and rank=2  from the other it doesn't qualify for selection.  So both `rnk=1` and `having count..` are requiered.

Comment: OP needs: *I want to find the team with the most points from every category.* This cannot be "the team which has the greatest points in any category" (with high probability there is no such team), so it is "the team which have the greatest points in at least one category". PS. Read the task as "I want to find (the team with the most points) from every category."

Comment: @Akina,  post your answer  so OP can choose which one is correct. I've read it exactly as  "greatest points in every category".